# Spanning Lists to multiple lines

Tags: html, css, list

I have the following code and for the life of me cannot get the text to break and display beneath the image like it would in a table.

```
<ul style="display:block inline; list-style:none;">
<li style="display:inline"><img src="BoxCover-01.jpg" /><br />Title 01</li>
<li style="display:inline"><img src="BoxCover-02.jpg" /><br />Title 02</li>
<li style="display:inline"><img src="BoxCover-03.jpg" /><br />Title 03</li>
<li style="display:inline"><img src="BoxCover-04.jpg" /><br />Title 04</li>
<li style="display:inline"><img src="BoxCover-05.jpg" /><br />Title 05</li>
</ul>
```

Ideally I would like to hide the bullets and display inline. The list items need to elegantly cascade beneath each other depending on the content width too.

This will be put in to a blog post to display a block of nominated films/dvds.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Should be `<ul style='display:inline-block;list-style:none;'>`.

Comment: i think you'll need to put the display: inline-block on the <li>'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LQxE2/1/), you had some erroneous display properties (block inline instead of inline-block), I've also tightened up your markup

HTML

```
<ul >
<li ><img src="BoxCover-01.jpg" />Title 01</li>
<li ><img src="BoxCover-02.jpg" />Title 02</li>
<li ><img src="BoxCover-03.jpg" />Title 03</li>
<li ><img src="BoxCover-04.jpg" />Title 04</li>
<li ><img src="BoxCover-05.jpg" />Title 05</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
li{
    display:inline-block;
}
img{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options:

**Option 1**

The `<img>` needs set as `display:block`. This will force your text to a new line and take away the need for the `<br>`

***Demo:***

http://jsfiddle.net/Gzd8m/1/

**Option 2**

A `<span>` needs introduced to the markup and set as `display:block`. This will also force your text to a new line and take away the need for the `<br>`

***Demo:***

http://jsfiddle.net/Gzd8m/2/

Answer (score 0):

you should not use `</br>` for this, you also should correct this:

```
display:inline-block;
```

instead of

```
display:block inline;
```